# My label is not appearing when value is null in dropdownsearch in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `DropDownSearch` in flutter, but the label is not working properly. When the variable passed in `value` parameter is null, label is shown on button itself. If I tap on the button or select a value, then it is showing the label correctly. Why and how to fix that?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Just put this line in `InputDecoration` in `dropdownsearchdecoration` parameter:

```
floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).